# Question about integrating Slack API with Github API

Tags: java, spring, github-api, slack-api

I'm trying to create a Slack app and integrate it with Github's API.

So for example whenever a Slack user performs a slash command like `/repositories` my web app (Spring boot) will make a request to Github and fetch all the repositories.

My question is, how do I get the `installation_id` in order to make this call to `/user/installations/{installation_id}/repositories`.

How do I know which Slack client owns which Github installation?